# how to make an auto line break in jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, line-breaks

hi I'm using java jtable

```
 dff[i] = new DefaultTableModel(
                        new Object[][] {
                            {"ID",tab[i].get("id")},
                            {"Titre",tab[i].get("title")},
                            {"Auteur",tab[i].get("authors")},
                            {"Date",tab[i].get("date")},
                            {"Resume","Substitution ciphers are codes in which each letter of the alphabet has one fixed substitute, and the word divisions do not change.."},
                        },
                        new String[] {
                            "New column",""
                        }
                    );

             jj[i]= new JTable(dff[I]);
```

but I'm getting

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCuNn.png]

I wanna add an auto break line in the abstract part if it's possible

Comment: I don't think that's the right image...

Comment: @Nosrep, You may be right, but it could be a two column table with custom renderers.

Comment: @camickr Sorry, didn't look closely enough

Comment: There is no easy way to do a line break. You could use a JTextArea as the renderer, but that also get complicated because then you need to start playing with the row height.

Comment: so there is no way to do a multi-line paragraph in one cellule of Jtable without Jtextarea?? (sorry about my eng)

Comment: You can also use HTML which can force wrapping of text, but this would not change dynamically if the column width is change. Also, you have the same problem of knowing what the proper height should be for the row. Many people will just set the tool tip so you can see all the text

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much camickr  I added `<HTML> <p>` and its work

```
tab[i].get("abstract")="Substitution ciphers are codes in which each letter of the alphabet has one fixed substitute, and the word divisions do not change.";

{"Resume","<html><p>"+tab[i].get("abstract")+"</p></html>"}
```

Comment: But that does not change the row height in the JTable. What else did you do so that you can see the text displayed on multiple lines?